# Obtain a constant result using kNN and decision tree in python

Tags: python, random, decision-tree, knn, training-data

I'm doing a project using the breast cancer dataset.
I implemented the kNN model and the decision tree model but when I try to find the best value for k the result changes every time I run the code.

```js
# Finding the optimum number of neighbors 

list1 = []

for k in range(1,20):
    kNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    kNN.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    y_pred = kNN.predict(X_test)

    # compute Accuracy on test set
    a = accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_pred)
    print ("k:", k, " | Accuracy:",  a)
    
    list1.append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
    
plt.plot(list(range(1,20)), list1)
plt.show()
```

```html
all_train_acc = []
all_test_acc = []
leaves_vals = range(2,20)

for max_leaves in range(2,20):
    # train and predict
    dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=max_leaves, random_state = None)
    dt.fit(X_train,y_train)

    # compute Accuracy
    train_acc = accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred=dt.predict(X_train))
    test_acc = accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=dt.predict(X_test))
    print ("Max leaves:", max_leaves, " - Train Accuracy:", train_acc, " - Test Accuracy:", test_acc)
    
    all_train_acc.append(train_acc)
    all_test_acc.append(test_acc)
    

plt.figure()
plt.plot(leaves_vals, all_train_acc)
plt.plot(leaves_vals, all_test_acc)
plt.legend(['train','test'])
plt.xlabel('max leaves')
```

I'd like to have the same resul every time the code runs, because I have to write a report on the project and I need to show why I get some conclusions and things like that. And a value that changes every time will make it difficult.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Classification with decision trees and other methods often involves random elements. This is often needed in statistical analysis. There are good reasons for this that go well beyond an answer here. Reading the documentation of DecisionTreeClassifier will already help.

It is often true that what you describe is

1. either due to a poorly constructed problem/analysis in the first place,
2. or alternatively, is part of the true answer to the problem.

The details of your analysis are not clear from the question and would require a complete and careful discussion (not suited for stackoverflow).

I could well imagine that point 2 is the case here, thus, the random nature of your answer is part of the solution to the problem. In this case, repeating the experiment often enough to get a good understanding of the statistical nature of the outcome is needed and the only valid way to proceed.

Since this is not an infrequent issue, there are also ways to help to study this on library level. Read

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state

and try setting the random_state to something fix. This should fix the apparent randomness, but it also my fool you to some extend since the answer you get is just a random result from a distribution of possible equally-valid answers. Hopefully those answers are all close together, otherwise the entire problem is ill-formed. You can study this a bit and write some paragraph on your findings in order to motivate this procedure.

This answer may help you with your concrete problem, but I also hope it will help you to become curious to understand the origin of the problem and why this may not be a problem in the first place.